# Deploying openserch in docker with pre-prepared data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, opensearch

Is it possible to deploy opensearch using docker-compose immediately with a set of data from a file?

The official documentation says that you need to deploy the docker image and then send a bulk request with data there. But nowhere does it say how to raise opensearch immediately with pre-prepared data.

Now I deploy opensearch like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  opensearch-node1:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest
    container_name: opensearch-node1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data1:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:latest
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["https://opensearch-node1:9200"]'

volumes:
  opensearch-data1:
```

Comment: Have you considered creating an image with the data on board? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/